# How to run Spark 3.3.0 Cosmos OLTP connector in Batch mode

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, spark-streaming, batch-processing, spark-structured-streaming

I have a use case to read data from `cosmosdb` in batch mode. It is able to read the data but not able to write. Job is running continuously. I am using `cosmos.oltp` connector in `spark 3.3.0`, `scala 2.12` and `java 11` but i think the default behavior of this connector is streaming mode. Is there anyway to disable the default behavior or enable the batch mode behavior?

maven dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.azure.cosmos.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure-cosmos-spark_3-3_2-12</artifactId>
       <version>4.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

```java
    Dataset<Row> cosmosDB = spark.read()
            .format("cosmos.oltp")
            .option("spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint","Endpoint")
            .option("spark.cosmos.accountKey","master_key")
            .option("spark.cosmos.database","database")
            .option("spark.cosmos.container","container")
            .option("preferredRegions","Region")
            .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled","true")
            .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.includeSystemProperties","true")
            .option("spark.cosmos.read.partitioning.strategy","Restrictive")
            .load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of reading from `container1` and writing to `container2` in batch using Cosmos OLTP Spark Connector and Scala:

```
val cfg = Map("spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" -> "Endpoint",
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" -> "master_key",
  "spark.cosmos.database" -> "database",
  "preferredRegions" -> "Region",
  "spark.cosmos.write.strategy" -> "ItemOverwrite",
  "spark.cosmos.write.bulk.enabled" -> "true"
)

val cosmosDB = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp")
  .options(cfg)
  .option("spark.cosmos.container","container1")
  .load();

cosmosDB.write.format("cosmos.oltp")
  .options(cfg)
  .option("spark.cosmos.container","container2")
  .mode("APPEND")
  .save()
```

See also [Quickstart for Cosmos DB Spark 3 OLTP Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-spark?tabs=scala), and several more complex samples for various types of operation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/Samples).

I'd also recommend using the [throughput control  feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/throughput-control-spark) if you want to lower the impact to steady state workloads from your batch runs.